# Error when executing Get-AzureStorageAccount in azure powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

Here is the error

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-AzureStorageAccount
Get-AzureStorageAccount : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: resource
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureStorageAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureStorageAccount], AadAuthenticationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.Authentication.AadAuthenticationFailedException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.StorageServices.GetAzureStorageAccountCommand
```

I am getting the same error on

Get-AzureLocation,
  Get-AzureWebsite

I have imported my settings file and Get-AzureSubscription works just fine and provides me all the correct information.

Comment: Did you run `Select-AzureSubscription first`? Does the output of `Get-AzureSubscription -current` contain a certificate?

Comment: when you import a settings file the subscription is automatically set as current and default. and yes I can see the certificate.

Comment: I can see there is something wrong with my computer as I can do the same operation on another computer and it works fine. some old credential is cached. may be.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue, got this from Microsoft support forum.

As far as my research goes on this, the issue can be related to cache of some account. If just adding does not work, I suggest that you remove and add the subscription again:

This article will give you information on this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495268.aspx